# Inserting data user has entered into mysql (java)

Tags: java, mysql, textfield, sql-insert

This is the code for a textField where user will insert data, after the program is started. It doesn't update the mysql table. Why it doesn't work?

```
textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/csprogram","root","");
                price=scan.next();
                String query = "INSERT * INTO `graphics` (price (KM)) VALUES (?);";
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                 preparedStmt.setString (1, price);
                 preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
            }
                catch (Exception d) {
                System.out.println("Error found "+ d);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: You have invalid syntax in the `INSERT`. Try with `"INSERT INTO graphics (price) VALUES (?)"` and post the error message you receive if it still doesn't work.

Comment: How does the table definition for `graphics` look like?

Comment: Do I maybe have to update all columns inside the table? because price(KM) is one of them 8. It doesn't show the error message with either procedure. It just freezes the program and I have to stop the console. How should I get the table definition, I don't have that in my code?

Comment: You need to get the table definition from the database. We cannot answer which columns are mandatory before you give us the definition, including auto generated columns, possible not null constraints etc. Anyways, your column name should be surrounded with quotes because it contains parentheses (`"price(KM)"`).

Answer (score 0):

you are doing everything inside actionPerformed() method which is local to the method. If you want to update mysql table either you have open do the same stuff or change your program accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
textField = new JTextField();
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/csprogram","root","");
            price=scan.next();
// Insert query shouldn't have *
            String query = "INSERT INTO `graphics` (price (KM)) VALUES (?);";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
             preparedStmt.setString (1, price);
             preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        }
            catch (Exception d) {
            System.out.println("Error found "+ d);
        }

    }
});
```